# In Spring MVC, is there a way to generate a list of recognized Controllers and Views?

Tags: spring-mvc

In annotation-driven Spring MVC, is there a way to generate a table of URL patterns, verbs, and their mappings? Something like:

```
 /foo/{fooId}       | GET | FooController.get()     | jsp/foo/home.jsp      |
 /foo/{fooId}/bars/ | GET | FooController.getBars() | jsp/foo/bar/index.jsp |
```

Comment: Not an answer but might be helpful... turn on DEBUG level logging for org.springframework (log4J config). When container is starting up you get a list of URI patterns with their matching controllers and methods (don't think you get HTTP verb or JSP path)

Answer (score 10):

this has helped me. inside log4j.xml put the following:

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.http">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
    <!-- below alternate between debug and info -->
<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Comment: worked for me but note that this is not all you need in your xml file.. need this also... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

Answer (score 5):

This is the same approach as john fuhr mentioned except more specific so you only log the URL mappings, not everything from the spring framework. I also use log4j.properties, instead of the .xml but you can convert it across if you like. I'm assuming you have an appender named `mainAppender` defined too.

I'm using Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE but it may work with other versions too.

This logger is responsible for anything you mark with a `@RequestMapping`:

```
  log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=INFO, mainAppender
```

This is the logger responsible for `<mvc:resources />` definitions:

```
  log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping=INFO, mainAppender
```

You may also want to add these two lines to stop duplicate output (printing the same line twice) if you experience that.

```
  log4j.additivity.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=false
  log4j.additivity.org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping=false
```

This is an example of the output I get:

```
14:29:43  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod():185 - Mapped "{[/splash],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String au.org.example.HomeController.splash(org.springframework.ui.Model)
14:29:43  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod():185 - Mapped "{[/home],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String au.org.example.HomeController.home(boolean,int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
14:29:44  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler():302 - Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
14:29:44  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler():315 - Mapped URL path [/js/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
14:29:44  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler():315 - Mapped URL path [/images/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'
14:29:44  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler():315 - Mapped URL path [/css/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2'
```

It's not as pretty as what you're after but it does give you the first three columns of information (from your example table). You don't get the view names unfortunately.